# JSON + jQuery $.post + Django --> parsererror - SyntaxError: invalid label

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json

For some reason I'm getting "**SyntaxError: invalid label**" error when I receive JSON data (see below) from a django function. Any ideas?

```
{ "id": "325", "from_date": "09-19-2011", "to_date": "09-20-2011" }
```

This is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
$(".edit_rec").click(function () {
    var rec_id = $(this).attr('name');
    $.post("/edit/", {
        editid: rec_id
    }, function (json) {
        var content = $.parseJSON(json);
        var to = new String(content.to_date);
        var from = new String(content.from_date);
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the reason for using `new String`? And is this the complete response?

Comment: When I click on the link (edit_rec) I first get a window saying "parsererror" then "SyntaxError: invalid label" and then "{ "id": "325", "from_date": "09-19-2011", "to_date": "09-20-2011" }". "String" I'm not sure if is necessary since the values come already as strings.

Comment: Removed the "new String" from my code. Same error "SyntaxError: invalid label"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add "json" after the callback to let jquery know that the return data should be json. jQuery will then automatically parse your json string into a JavaScript object.

```
$(".edit_rec").click(function () {
    var rec_id = $(this).attr('name');
    $.post("/edit/", {
        editid: rec_id
    }, function (content) {
        var to = new String(content.to_date);
        var from = new String(content.from_date);
    },"json");
});
```

Comment: Great answer! It's worth asking for directions once in a while. It's said that we man don't like to do that :-)